# Significance testing of A/B test with poisson distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, poisson-distribution

I am evaluating results of an A/B-style experiment where we have different groups of people that can perform a target action. They can do the target action as many times as they want, but most people don't do this very often (poisson distribution).

I'm interested in how I can best calculate the statistical significance of the impact on the number of times they do the target action, similar how a normal A/B test works. How can I do this? Can I use a normal t-test?